# An odd point in a cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Consider the following cubic equation:
$$ax^3+bx^2+c $$
For $a=b=c=1$, the graph looks like this:

[image]

There are three points marked on the image, the root, the highest point in that 'slope', and the y intercept.

I am most concerned with the middle point, at the top of the arc in the first quadrant. Why is the x position (seemingly) the average between the root and the y intercept? And why is the y position $1.148$? Is there an expression for that point in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: How is the x position the average of the root and y intercept?

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly identified that the $x$ value of the point is $-\frac23$ (but incorrectly concluded that it is the half of the x value of the root). To get the $y$ value simply substitute into your equation:

$$y(-\frac23)=(-\frac23)^2+(-\frac{23})^2+1$$

$$y(-\frac23)=-\frac{8}{27}+\frac{4}{9}+1$$

$$y(-\frac23)=-\frac{8}{27}+\frac{12}{27}+\frac{27}{27}$$

$$y(-\frac23)=\frac{31}{27}$$

$$y(\frac23)\approx1.14815\cdots$$

For the general case of any $a$ and $b$ you need some calculus to work out the coordinate of the point.

The answer comes out to be: $x=-\frac{2b}{3a}$ which then is substitued back into $y$ to give:

$$y=\frac{4b^3}{27a^2}+c$$

Answer (score 1):

That middle point which you describe as the "highest point in the slope" is known as a local maximum. You would normally find it in terms of $a$ and $b$ using calculus.

Let $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ be any cubic graph. Then the local minimums (troughs) and maximums (peaks) can be found by differentiating $f(x)$ to find the values of $x$ where the slope of the graph is $0$. So:

$$
f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \\
f'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c \\
$$

If you solve for all the values of x where $f'(x) = 0$, that is where the local minima and maxima occur. In your case, $f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1$ and so $f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2x$.

Solving for $f'(x) = 0$ we get:

$$
f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2x = 0 \\
x(3x + 2) = 0 \\
\implies x=0 \ \text{ or }\ x=\frac{-2}{3}
$$

Thus you have a trough or a peak at $x=0$ and $x=\frac{-2}{3}$. Note this agrees with the picture of the graph as there is a local minimum at $x=0$ and a local maximum at $x=\frac{-2}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x^3+x^2+1$, then

$$f'(x) = 3x^2+2x = x(3x+2)$$

$f'(x)=0 \implies x=0$ or $-\frac{2}{3}$

Also, $f(0)=1$ and $f\left( -\frac{2}{3} \right)=\frac{31}{27}$

Now $(0,1)$ is the local minimum and $\left( -\frac{2}{3},\frac{31}{27} \right)$ is the local maximum.

The only real root is at $x=-\frac{1}{3} \left( \sqrt[3]{\frac{29+3\sqrt{93}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{29-3\sqrt{93}}{2}}+1 \right)$.

Answer (score 1):

When you have some real-valued function $y(x)$, then

- Roots are the values of $x$ where $y(x) = 0$
- Peaks, or local extrema, occur when $\frac{d \, y(x)}{d x} = 0$

Here we have
$$y(x) = a x^3 + b x^2 + c$$
and its derivative is
$$\frac{d y(x)}{d x} = 3 a x^2 + 2 b x$$

To find the local extrema, we set the derivative to zero, and solve for $x$:
$$3 a x^2 + 2 b x = x (3 a x + 2 b) = 0$$
which we can solve directly, either $x = 0$ or $3 a x + 2 b = 0$, thus
$$\frac{d y(x)}{d x} = 0, \; \text{ if } \; x = 0 \; \text{ or } \; x = -\frac{2 b}{3 a}$$
which means the curve has local extrema at $x = 0$ and at $x = -\frac{2 b}{3 a}$, which are clearly shown in OP's diagram.

Other real valued functions are just as easy to solve. Note that all real

- Linear functions $$y(x) = C_1 x + C_0, \; C_1 \ne 0$$
  have at most one root, but no maxima; their derivative is constant ($= C_1$)
- Quadratic functions $$y(x) = C_2 x^2 + C_1 x + C_0, \; C_2 \ne 0$$ have up to two roots and one local extrema (and because there is only one possible local extrema, it is also the global extremum, i.e. minimum or maximum point)
- Cubic functions $$y(x) = C_3 x^3 + C_2 x^2 + C_1 x + C_0, \; C_3 \ne 0$$ have up to three roots and two local extrema
- Quartic functions $$y(x) = C_4 x^4 + C_3 x^3 + C_2 x^2 + C_1 x + C_0, \; C_4 \ne 0$$ have up to four roots and three local extrema
- Algebraic solutions exist for the roots of up to cubic functions; for higher-degree ones, only if they happen to be of some special form
- Algebraic solutions exist for the extrema of up to quartic functions; for higher-degree ones, only if their derivatives happen to have some special form